# Receiving a a weird message from VS CODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.7

I was trying to do use datetime for the first time Visual Studio Code with python3.
this is my code

```
from datetime import date, time, datetime
datetime(year=2020, month=10, day=7, hour=9, minute=30, second=0)
```

It gave me this

/usr/bin/python3 "/Users/myname/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/Python/clock.py"

is this a error and why is my code not running i am a beginner so this might be a dumb question
I come from pycharm were i would have to add the import to the interpreter something like this
[pycharm interpreter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFRpa.png)

Comment: The code should work. It seems that it is the path to your python interpreter and the path to the module called  ´clock.py` (your module?) and it seems you are on a Mac and storing the script in a cloud synced directory?

Comment: What makes you think this is an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/usr/bin/python3` part is the python interpreter that you're using to open `.py` file, in your case, that would be `clock.py` which is located in the `/Users/myname/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/Python` directory. It's just a more verbose way to say `python3 clock.py`.